# Writing an array to a CSV file

Tags: arrays, excel, fortran

I a trying to create an array and output it to an excel with the correct rows and columns. But when I run the code below, it gives me them in all in one column and 16 rows. Any way i can change it so that it gives it to me in 4 columns and 4 rows?

```
do i = 1, 4
  do j = 1, 4

    test(i,j) = 2

    print *, test(i,j)
    open( unit = 10, file = "test.csv")
    write(10,*), test(i,j)
  end do
end do
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130384/how-to-write-fortan-output-as-csv-file

Comment: If you want to open in Excel, tab delimited is easier than csv.  You can create a tab by typing char(9) wherever you want the tab to go.

Answer (score 2):

Some things first: If you do file i/o, you need to open and close the file. You only need to do this once.

Next, each `write` statement will (unless explicitly stated otherwise), advance the line.

The easiest way to get what you seem to want is this:

```
test(:, :) = 2
open(unit=10, file='test.csv')
do j = 1, 4
    write(10, *) test(1:4, j)
end do
close(10)
```

But this is not comma separated. Assuming that `test` is an integer array, you could modify the `write` statement above to this:

```
write(10, '(3(I0, ", "), I0)') test(1:4, j)
```

**Update:** I just confirmed @mark-s suggestion:

```
write(10, '(*(I0 : ", "))') test(:, j)
```

This is even better as you don't have to know the size of the array.

Or, even better, and described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130384/how-to-write-fortan-output-as-csv-file), you could use a **CSV module**

Comment: Great answer.  Here is another way to acheive the same format: write(10, '(*(I0 : ","))') test(1:4,j).  The difference is mostly the : in the format statement says that everything after it only repeats if there is data.  This is another way to eliminate the trailing comma.  I also used the * unlimited format item instead of counting items.  That is a fairly new feature I think.

Comment: Thanks for that info, I hadn't know that. Very useful.

Comment: The star is a fairly new feature, but it was always possible to just use a large integer like `999999`. You don't have to know the exact size. This was the common way before Fortran 2008 (and in compilers which don't support it).