# Fortran, write 2d array into excel file

Tags: arrays, excel, fortran

Hello I am having trouble writing a 2d array into an excel file.

I would like to have the values in a 10 x 10 format in excel, but this error keeps popping up I am not sure how to fix it.

code3.f90:40:12:

```
write(10, (b(i,j), j = 1,10)
        1
```

Error: Syntax error in WRITE statement at (1)
x-10-104-223-3:cht

Here is my initial code

```
do i = 1, 10
    do j = 1, 10

            b(i, j) = 1
    end do
end do



do i = 1,10
open( unit = 10, file = "test.csv")
write(10, (b(i,j), j = 1,10)
end do
```

Comment: Apart from the format issue: you should not keep re-opening the file in the do-loop. Instead place the `open` command before the `do` command.

Comment: Very closely related, though not exactly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35495289/2737715

Answer (score 2):

You have the `write`syntax wrong. You need to specify the format as a second part in the parenthesis, the output items go outside:

```
write(10,*) (b(i,j), j = 1,10)
```

Here, the format `*` is used to indicate list-directed output to "let the compiler decide on the exact output format" (depending on the output items).

As remarked by@cars10 in a comment: opening the file inside the loop is a bad idea. The code will probably exit with an error in the second iteration. Put the statement in front of the loop body.